# How to make sum function passing arguments through return function?

Tags: javascript

This is a simplified version with addition of 2 numbers:

```js
const sum = (a) => {
  return function(b) {
    return a + b;
  }
}

console.log(
  sum(2)(2)
);
```

This is a more difficult option.

I couldn't find this problem on google, but I'm just wondering how to solve this. I couldn't think of a solution.

```js
const sum = (a) => {
  // How to make it?
}

console.log(
  sum(2)(2)(4)() // Expected result: 8
  sum(2)(2)(4)(4)(4)() // Expected result: 16
  sum(2)(2)(4)(10)(20)(1)() // Expected result: 39
);
```

Comment: "The number of arguments can be infinite ". That means the inner function should be able to accept variable number of arguments

Comment: var sum = (a) => {
  return function (b) {
    if (b) {
      return sum(a + b);
    } else {
      return a + 0;
    }
  };
};